# How to turn a single page of a large web site into a stand-alone PWA with Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, blazor-client-side

I have a web site with thousands of pages and more being added daily due to the fact that users can add a page for their own product and associated information. In addition to storing the data the user enters when creating a new page in a database to be used when serving that page, I want to be able to create a Blazor PWA with just that one page so the user can install it on their device(s) and see updates to comments, etc. as the changes occur. My questions are these:

Can I programmatically create a Blazor PWA and then send the user the link so they can install just that one page on their device?

Can a Blazor server app contain Blazor client pages?